# c++ lambda with implicit return?

Tags: c++, lambda

In below code, with c++17 `std::find_if`, the `return` in the comparison predicate is necessary.

```
auto it = find_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [](int i) { return i == 1; });
```

In situations where the return type of the lambda can be inferred (like here where it acts as a predicate), it would seem logical to be able have an implicit `return` from a lambda, so one could simply write:

```
auto it = find_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [](int i) { i == 1; });
```

Is that somehow possible? Do lambdas exist whose `return`-*intent* and `return`-*type* can and will be handled implicitly, according to usage-context?

Comment: No, this is not R. Second lambda has return type `void`.

Comment: worth reading: https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/01/15/abbrev-lambdas/

Comment: you can have lambdas that don't return something and you can have statements that do nothing. How would you distinguish your case from the case then `e == 1;` should not be returned?

Comment: @idclev463035818 would it not be able to be determined in certain usages, from usage-context?

Comment: No. And it just causes confusion either way.

Comment: @zen A lambda is a distinct type. It can't change base on where and how it's used. So determining returntype based on usage is not possible.

Comment: actually it is the opposite. `find_if` is a template and one of its parameters is deduced from the type of that lambda. You are asking for deduction in the opposite direction

Comment: ok, but it would seem that the lamda would be one and the same, the ommitance of return would be syntactic sugar, applicable when the return type *is* clear, and it *is* clear that a return is expected?

Comment: @idclev463035818 ah!! thats a good answer, understood, thx!

Comment: I'm always surprised how far people are willing to go just to save in typing a few characters. What about the fact that all of a sudden the syntax inside a lambda would be different from anywhere else in your code. Wouldn't that be confusing? Why would you want a language to be written in a way that you need to know all these little extra "shortcuts" to understand what i means.

Comment: fwiw, I sometimes wish similar for plain functions. Wouldn't it be handy to have an implicit `result` declared of the type that the function returns and when the the function returns this will implicitly be returned? It is tempting, but (as super already wrote in the meanwhile) I dont think being lazy to type a few letters is a valid motivation to change the core of a language

Comment: @super, i think the formulation in this case would cause no confusion and the lambda would look somewhat more like a predicate. i think the good reason for not allowing it here, not being possible is that it is the lamda that determines the template instantiation and so that return-intent must be explicit.

Comment: understanding that in the present case it is not doable, i think normal function return is well serving clarity, lamdas often have a very narrow context of application and they themselves are a tool that is often aimed at brevity.

Comment: @ecatmur https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/01/15/abbrev-lambdas/ is very interesting and useful, if you want to post as an answer (just the link) i will accept it as an answer.

Comment: i have to take back part of what I said above. What barry suggested in that proposal looks awesome, a pitty that it didnt work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [proposal](https://wg21.link/p0573r2) for "abbreviated" lambdas with the syntax:

```
auto it = find_if(V.begin(), V.end(), [](int i) => i == 1);
                                                ^^ abbreviated-lambda operator token
```

However, this was rejected for [a number of reasons](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/01/15/abbrev-lambdas/), chief among them that it would have introduced an inconsistency for lambdas that could return a reference:

```
[](int* p) { return *p; } // returns `int`
[](int* p) => *p          // returns `int&`
```

There is still interest in shorter lambda syntax, so it may come along at some point, possibly with a different syntax.